# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in double loop

Tags: matlab

need help with this error.

nc=2;
kk=1;

```
for f=1:nc
for j=1:n
    SS=2*j-1;
    for s=1:SS-1
        totalI=totalI+tI;
    end
    tin=totalI+tI;
    RI(kk,:)=RI+P(j,n)*tin; %error in this line
    kk=kk+1;
end
totalI=0;
end
```

thank you so much!

Comment: Should that line be `RI(kk,:)=RI(kk,:)+P(j,n)*tin;` instead? Not tested though.

Comment: it come to new error: Attempted to access RI(2,:); index out of bounds because numel(RI)=1.

Comment: it's likely because you defined kk equal to 1 before the loop

Comment: RI will give 10 different results. It will loop 10 times.

Comment: Then I guess just `RI(kk,:)=P(j,n)*tin;` would do.

Comment: On a sidenote, that innermost loop is completely unnecessary, since you don't use the loop variable. You should consider replacing it with `tin = totalI + SS*tI`.

Comment: @Divakar RI=0...the base calculation is a loop RI=RI+P(j,n)*tin based on P(j,n) value...In order to plot a graph, I need 10 value, so I add RI(kk,:)=RI+P(j,n)*tin; kk=kk+1; to get 10 value in one execution. But the error occur. Is that mean I misplaced (kk,:)?                                   **sorry sobek & other commenter, inpurposely deleting ur latest comments, my bad.

Comment: @NorH Did you try - `RI(kk,:)=P(j,n)*tin;`? In the end you would have all the values in that array `RI`.

Comment: I did but it will effect 2nd loop for RI, for example 1st loop RI=2, 2nd loop suppose RI=2+P(j,n)*tin. It will give wrong answer at the end. TQ

Comment: @NorH After exiting from the loop do this - `RI = cumsum(RI)`.